# How to rename field names in a shapefile from the commandline?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, convert, ogr

I need to rename the field names (attributes) in a shapefile. Is there an easy way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 36):

You can use the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility which is packaged with the [gdal command line tools](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries). Use the `-sql` option as follows:

```
ogr2ogr outputfile.shp inputfile.shp -sql "SELECT oldfield1 AS newfield1, oldfield2 AS newfield2 from inputfile"
```

As an added bonus, you can convert the data into a different format at the same time, or filter your data by specifying a where clause. Note that you will need to specify all output fields if you use this method (any fields not included in the SELECT statement will be dropped from the output file).

- Solution via
  http://darrencope.com/2011/04/26/renaming-fields-in-a-shapefile/
- See
  also
  http://www.sarasafavi.com/intro-to-ogr-part-ii-creating-new-data.html

Comment: You can also list the field names using `ogrinfo -so inputfile.shp inputfile`

Comment: A side note: this method only works when transforming shapefiles. For example if using GeoJSON data format you need to first convert it to a shapefile, then do another transformation using the `-sql` flag.

Comment: Also you should add -dialect SQLITE option otherwise ogr2ogr will throw an error 6: output_file.shp must contain at least one attribute 1 field