# How to rename PostgreSQL/PostGIS columns while importing Shapefiles?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, import

I discovered `shp2psql` to successfully import geospatial data from ESRI Shapefiles into PostgreSQL/PostGIS.
Now I would like to automatically **rename the target column names**. Is there any mechanism where I can define the original column names and their corresponding target column names in something such as a look-up table? Or would you do the renaming within the database using triggers or rules? Or do you recommend another import tool?

Comment: It looks like the -f flag can be used for this based upon [PostGIS 2.0 pgsql2shp shp2pgsql Command Line Cheatsheet](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg)

Comment: @RyanDalton is -f for the filename rather than a column name in the destination file?

Comment: I suspect you will have to use postgre sql to rename the columns after the import. See the renaming columns section on this page  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-alter.html

Comment: @mapBaker, you are correct.  -f is for filename, not column name.  Ummm... yeah... I really meant what LR1234567 said :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To expand on David Bitner's answer, here's an example [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) instruction demonstrating an optional [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) clause to rename fields from a source dataset (shapefile in this case) before they are brought into a target dataset (a PostGREsql table):

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostGreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=YourUser dbname=YourDB password=YourPass"
"E:\path\to\YourShapefile.shp" -nln NewTableName -nlt geometry 
-sql "SELECT col_1 AS BetterName, col_2 AS ImprovedName FROM YourShapefile" 
-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom
```

- `-nln` Allows you to provide a name for the new PostGREsql table
- `-nlt` Will allow multipart and singlepart features to exist in the same table
- `-sql` The OGR SQL clause renaming the source fields
- `-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom` By default ogr2ogr names the geometry field `wkb_geometry`, but we can use a [Layer Creation Option](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html) (`-lco`) to name it something else, like `the_geom` so it will share this convention with shp2pgsql..

**Gotchas**: A valid `ogr2ogr` instruction should not have any line breaks. Also, I've had trouble copying single quotes (') and double quotes (") from web examples and pasting them into the terminal. Perhaps it's a weird unicode issue? So it's recommended to type your command in a simple text editor like notepad before pasting it into the terminal. Or just type it directly into the terminal. Either way the point is beware copy-and-pasted quotes and double quotes.

Comment: I just noticed [a similar answer provided here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58541/how-to-rename-field-names-in-a-shapefile-from-the-commandline) in the context of shapefile-to-shapefile, which includes some links to additional reading on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

JJD yes there is.  I haven't used it myself.

You use the -m option and pass a mapping file that has the old column name and new column name on each line.  As Ryan alluded to here:

http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg

I suspect he was thinking of -m and mistyped -f.

Hope that helps,
Regina

Comment: Although I have installed `postgis 2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg13.10+2` there is no `-m` option listed in the man page of `shp2psql 2.1.3 (r12547)`. I am running Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I found the feature mentioned in [ticket #885](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/885) as well as in the [changelog](http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/ChangeLog). Is the `-m` option listed in your version? If so, which version do you use?

Comment: Actually, the `-m` option seems to be not implemented for `shp2psql` as stated in [ticket #899](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/899). The cheatsheet only lists the option for `pgsql2shp` - notice the columns `P` and `S`.

Comment: Ah yes you are right.  Sorry about that.  I should read my own cheatsheets.  I upgraded the related ticket to implement the same feature in shp2pgsql to 2.2.0 -- http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/899  I'll try to work on it before release.

Comment: JJD if you can compile your own PostGIS I have the -m option committed for PostGIS 2.2 (trunk) http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/899  Just trying to settle some windows/linux bot fights so I might need to rework it a bit.  Anyrate give it a try if you can.

Comment: For more info on the `-m` flag see: https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage

Answer (score 4):

You can use ogr2ogr with the -sql option to use a sql statement

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I'd do, too. Here's an example [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) call with [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html): `ogr2ogr -f "PostGreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=YourUser dbname=YourDB password=YourPass" "E:\path\to\YourShapefile.shp" -nln NewTableName -nlt geometry -sql "SELECT col_1 AS BetterName, col_2 AS ImprovedName FROM YourShapefile"`

Comment: @elrobis Works fine. Please convert your comment into a full answer to I can grant you the answer flag. Thanks to David for pointing into the right direction.

Comment: @JJD, done. I feel kinda bad stealing the points though, so I expanded on it a little more than I did in the comment.

Comment: and what if the table has 100 columns/fields but you only want to rename a couple? Want to avoid using `-sql` flag with 100 fields written out.