# How to rename PostgreSQL/PostGIS columns while importing from WFS, using OGR?

Tags: postgis, wfs, ogr2ogr

so I'm trying to rename PostgreSQL/PostGIS columns when importing from **WFS** using `ogr2ogr`.

The post [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107533/how-to-rename-postgresql-postgis-columns-while-importing-shapefiles) covers how to achieve this when importing from a **Shapefile**, using the `-sql` option like this:

```
-sql "SELECT col_1 AS BetterName, col_2 AS ImprovedName FROM YourShapefile"
```

However, as I'm importing from WFS, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=YourDB host=YourHost user=User password=Password active_schema=Schema" -nlt POLYGON -nln TableName "WFS:[WFS_URL_HERE]" -a_srs EPSG:4230 -sql "SELECT shape.area AS shape_area, shape.len AS shape_len FROM [What goes here?]"
```

How does the `-sql` option work in this particular use case? I have tried adding the WFS URL after the `FROM` clause, but this did not work.

Does anyone have any experience of this, is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layername should go there. 
If you need to know the layername first: You can achieve this by doing an ogrinfo:

```
 ogrinfo "WFS:[WFS_URL_HERE]"
```

Now, when you have the correct layername you do:

```
 ogrinfo -so "WFS:[WFS_URL_HERE]" "[LAYERNAME]"
```

This will give you the attributes. Finally you can do your full SELECT statement in the -sql parameter which will give you the option to alias.